# Mix up of the Characters while scanning number from two rows license plate

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am working on Indian license plates with python. I am getting totally wrong characters from this license plate for example:

```
License plate number:        PB10EB2640
after character recognition: 8P2B61400E
```

- [image, annotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVKhM.png)
- [image, annotated more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmCR8.jpg)
- [close-up, character segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pOf3.jpg)

My Code:

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
rect_kern = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))

dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, rect_kern, iterations = 1)
try:
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
except:
    ret_img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

im2 = gray.copy()

plate_num = ""
cv2.imshow("plate", im2)
# loop through contours and find individual letters and numbers in license plate
for cnt in sorted_contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    height, width = im2.shape
    # if height of box is not tall enough relative to total height then skip
    if height / float(h) > 6: continue

    ratio = h / float(w)
    # if height to width ratio is less than 1.5 skip
    if ratio < 1.5: continue

    # if width is not wide enough relative to total width then skip
    if width / float(w) > 15: continue

    area = h * w
    # if area is less than 100 pixels skip
    if area < 100: continue

    # draw the rectangle
    rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0),2) # will draw the rectangle outside each character
    # grab character region of image
    roi = thresh[y-5:y+h+5, x-5:x+w+5]
    # perfrom bitwise not to flip image to black text on white background
    roi = cv2.bitwise_not(roi)
    # perform another blur on character region
    roi = cv2.medianBlur(roi, 5)
    try:
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi, config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ --psm 8 --oem 3', lang='eng')
        # clean tesseract text by removing any unwanted blank spaces
        clean_text = re.sub('[\W_]+', '', text)
        plate_num += clean_text
    except: 
        text = None
if plate_num != None:
    print("License Plate #: ", plate_num)
#cv2.imshow("Character's Segmented", im2)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
if os.path.isfile('./plateimage/plate' + plate_num + '.jpg'):
    img1 = cv2.imread('./plateimage/plate' + plate_num + '.jpg',
                      cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img2 = im2
    laplacian_var1 = cv2.Laplacian(img1, cv2.CV_64F).var()
    laplacian_var2 = cv2.Laplacian(img2, cv2.CV_64F).var()

    if laplacian_var1 < laplacian_var2:
        print("===============")
        cv2.imwrite("./plateimage/" + 'plate' + plate_num + '.jpg', im2)

else:
    cv2.imwrite("./plateimage/" + 'plate' + plate_num + '.jpg', im2)
    csvdata = [datetime.datetime.now(), plate_num]
    with open("plateNumbers.csv", "a") as csvFile:
        Fileout = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
        Fileout.writerow(csvdata)
return plate_num
```

How can I improve it?

Comment: Be optimistic, it's quite correct, not "totally wrong".. Looks like your program scans for characters from left to right, without knowing there are two rows. So you need to separate your sorted_contours into two rows, then scan row by row.

Comment: @Guang thanku very much I got the point and I changed my " sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0]) " line to " sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0] + cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[1] * img.shape[1] )" and its solved :)

Comment: @Guang but now from single line number plate it recognizing from right to left if my number is : PB09AB7272 answer is: 27Z7B90BP how can i solve it?

Comment: If your answer has correct letters just reverse order, simply reverse it back; if your answer has some incorrect letters, that's probably the recognition code is confused.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your program scans for characters from left to right, without knowing there are two rows. So you need to separate your `sorted_contours` into two rows, then scan row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the lines of text is tricky in general. In the case of two superimposed words like you have, you can first find the tightest slanted rectangle that contains all characters, and that gives you the reading direction.

Then it becomes easy to find the characters facing each other or on different rows.

[image]